# van.dll,RunVAN Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, rundll32.exe

I'm trying to display the network pane (the one that appears when you click on the systray network icon ) snapshot of the icon

I saw on sevreal forums references to Rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN . This works great on Windows 8/8.1, but returns nothing on Windows 10 (no errors, no message). Unfortunatly, it doesn't show the panel.

Does anybody knows how to have this work ?

Rgds

---------------------------- Edit 11/18/15

I've updated my win10 x64 Education to the 1511 build but it's the same issue.
When i run this command :

> Rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN

or this command

> Rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVANW

The results is : no actions, no errors, the commands doesn't work. However, if i test to run an unexisting methods of van.dll like

> Rundll32.exe van.dll,fakeVAN

i got this error : "Error in VAN.dll, Missing entry : fakeVan"

I gather that other commands are recognized as correct, although they have no effects...

Commands work fine on my win 8.1 devices, not on win10 x64 (july & 1511 builds) on multiple devices tested

Comment: Have you been able to resolve your issue. I can confirm that opening the dialog does indeed NOT work in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in Windows 10 Version 1511 (Fall Update) and it works as expected:

[image]

[image]

> *As pointed out by the user [xpclient](https://superuser.com/users/452355/xpclient), it works only if [StartIsBack++](http://startisback.com/#download-tab) is
>   installed on Windows 10.*

Comment: I just updated to 1511 on my laptop with win10 x64 Education, same result, with commands RunVAN or RunVANW, no errors, no actions... but with for example, Rundll32.exe van.dll,fakeVAN, it's say : http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8IN2.png

Same way on a surface 3 also just updated to 1511, on an another laptop with July build of windows x64 home and on another type of device/version of win10...


Have you another specificities that can be differents on your config ?

Comment: @Khorwin - Can you provide the exact command you are running, and translate the error message, in the last screenshot you provided? Your last comment is confusing, try to clarify it, in an update to your question.

Comment: as you see for me it works. Can you open the network pane on your own?

Comment: @Ramhound i've just updated my question.

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, i can open it by click the systrayIcon

Comment: as I said, **Rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN** works fine for me

Comment: I've you an 32 or 64 version of win10 ? i've test on multiples devices, i can see where is different between our config...

Comment: I use the 64 Bit Windows 10 Pro (German language)

Comment: I can confirm that Rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN does not work on my PC either — it stopped working at the point that I upgraded in-place from 8.1 to 10 earlier this month (currently Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, US English). I've been using it to turn a True Launch Bar network status button into a replacement network icon.

I see the same behaviour as the OP: a DLL entry error with "fakeVAN" but nothing but a brief background activity cursor otherwise: RunVAN does nothing at all. It's not a big deal for me, but maybe I can answer some questions to help identify where this is going wrong.

Comment: @DanielBeardsmore for me it works fine. I have no idea why it fails for both of you

Answer (score 0):

Use `ms-availablenetworks:` commandline in windows 10 as replacement to `Rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN`